# CSS Problem: How to make the images in a <table> made of images touch vertically?

Tags: html, css, dhtml

In the page [Toggle Squares](http://www.shlomifish.org/MathVentures/toggle-squares/) , I have a table made out of an <img /> in every cell generated by JavaScript. I applied the following CSS:

```
.game, .game td, .game tr, .game img
{ 
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

In order to remove all spacing. However, now I'm getting a thin background line of spacing  between two adjacent rows. How can I eliminate it?

The page is valid XHTML + CSS.

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

[Shlomi Fish](http://www.shlomifish.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.game td img {
 display: block;
}
```

Images come with their own white space

Answer (score 5):

add cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" attributes to table, or try to use

```
border-collapse: collapse; 
border-width: 0;
```

in css..

Comment: I added the border-collapse and border-width attributes to the CSS and it still doesn't work. (Firefox 3.0.x).

Comment: what about cellpadding and cellspacing attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
.game, .game td, .game tr, .game img
{ 
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: inline image is treated as a letter with ascent = height of the image and descent = descent of the font. That means that a table cell that contains only an image has the height that is bigger than the image height.

The simplest way to fix that is to set line-height to zero for the whole table thus suppressing the descent in the text lines or set display: block for all images thus moving them out of inline formatting context into block formatting context.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the effect you are looking for with the following code:

The code depicts four solid colored jpegs right next to each other forming a square with no space inbetween:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td { margin 0px; padding: 0px;}
        table { border-collapse:collapse;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead />
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><img src="test.jpeg" /></td><td><img src="test.jpeg" /></td></tr>                   
            <tr><td><img src="test.jpeg" /></td><td><img src="test.jpeg" /></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```